# Question on Sections of Algebraic Curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, schemes

I have a question about a conclusion in the proof of lemma 7.4.3 from Liu's "Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves" (on page 286):

[image]

We assume that the invertible sheaf $O_{X}(D)$ is globally generated by $s_0,...,s_n \in L(D) =H^0(X,O_{X}(D))$. This fact gives rise for a morphism $f:X \to \mathbb{P}^n$ induced by the $s_i$.

Let $s \in H^0(X, O_{X}(D))/H^0(X, O_{X}(D))$ a section with $s = \sum_{0 \le i \le n}\lambda_i s_i$.

Let $f(p)=(p_0,..., p_n)$.

Since $O_{X}(D)$ locally free the stalk at $p$ is isomorphic to $O_{X,p}$ via $O_{X,p} \to O_{X}(D)_p, r \mapsto r \cdot e$ (where $e$ basis of $O_{X}(D)_p$).

We observe $(s_i)_p \in p_i \cdot e +\mathfrak{m}^2_p$.

The QUESTION is why does this imply $\sum_i \lambda_i p_i =0$?

I don't understand it.

Comment: $p_i$ means $s_i(p)$. If $p$ doesn't appear in the divisor $D\ge 0$ then $s \in L(D-p) \implies 0=s(p) = \sum \lambda_i s_i(p)$. Do they need to deal with the case $D = p+D'$ ?

Comment: $D = p+D'$ with $D'$ effective is a cruical case because this may imply that if $p$ is not appear in $D'$ then $s_p \not \in \mathfrak{m}_p O_X(D)$. I not see how the given assumptions allow to avoid or cope with this case. $p,q$ were not assumed to be distinct from $D$

Comment: In fact $p_i$ means $\frac{s_i}{ e}(p)$ so if $D = Np+D'$ then $e$ has a pole of order $N$ at $p$ and it cancels the pole of order $N-1$ of $s$. That $e \in L(D),\not \in L(D-p), s \in L(D-p) \implies 0=\frac{s}{ e}(p)= \sum \lambda_i \frac{s_i}{ e}(p)$. Dividing by $e$ doesn't change $f(p) =[s_0(p):\ldots:s_n(p)] = [\frac{s_0}{ e}(p):\ldots:\frac{s_n}{ e}(p)]$ that's why I confused.

Comment: I meant $e \in L(Np)O_{X,p}, \not \in L((N-1)p)O_{X,p}$ because it is only a local generator $O_X(D)_p =e\, O_{X,p}$.